# How to set DNS pointing for tumblr, when the nameserver opens for my website?

Tags: dns, tumblr, nameservers, a-records

Ok so I did everything tumblr asks to use a custom domain

A record pointing mydomain.com to  66 6 44 4 
A record pointing www mydomain com to  66 6 44 4 
Cname - pointing to domains tumblr com

And Tumblr says we don't have to change/erase our nameservers
BUT turns out that mydomain keeps opening the website from my server, instead of tumblr. Which sounds natural to me, so I can't understand how can the A record own my domain instead of the nameserver?

1-) I can't leave the nameserver empty, my domain hoster doesn't allow
2-) tumblr doesn't allow their IP to be pointed as nameservers.

help :(

Comment: When peple post here the actual domain names, it helps us to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

What you did is right, all you need are A records for domain.com and for www.domain.com. Nameservers are not relevant here.

The fact that your setup does not work originates from some other reason, maybe old records cached somewhere etc...

Comment: oh sandman, I'm so desperate. can't find out what is wrong :(